# Select id where all user id match

Tags: mysql

Okay, I get an array with multiple user ids from a php script.

Now I have this mysql table:

```
+ - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - - +
¦ fk_conversation       ¦   fk_user ¦
+ - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - - +
¦ 1                     ¦     2     ¦
+ - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - - +
¦ 1                     ¦     3     ¦
+ - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - - +
¦ 1                     ¦     4     ¦
+ - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - - +
¦ 2                     ¦     2     ¦
+ - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - - +
¦ 2                     ¦     4     ¦
+ - - - - - - - - - - - + - - - - - +
```

If I get the array (2,4) I need to get the `fk_conversation` key = 2 but if I get the array(2,3,4) I should get the `fk_conversation` key = 1.

I always want to get the `fk_conversation` id where all connected `fk_user` ids are in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select fk_conversation
from my_table
where fk_user in ( ARRAY VALUES )
and fk_conversation in (
    select fk_conversation
    from my_table
    group by fk_conversation having count(distinct fk_user) = ARRAY SIZE
)
group by fk_conversation
having count(distinct fk_user) = ARRAY SIZE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select fk_conversation 
    from table 
    where fk_user in ( comma separated array_values ) 
    group by fk_conversation 
    having count(fk_conversation) = array_size
```

Comment: No, doesn't work. it returns both fk_conversation ids. but in the end i only should get the fk_conversation id which is assigned to all id in the array but also only to all the id in the array.

Comment: did you write the correct sql? here is my example ... SELECT fk_conversation
FROM test
WHERE fk_user
IN ( 2, 3, 4 ) 
GROUP BY fk_conversation
HAVING COUNT( fk_conversation ) =3